# Documents needed to cross US border and back again into Canada on the same day if no passport is available

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, canadian-citizens

My daughter and I will be traveling from Canada to the US for a one-day lacrosse game on Saturday.

Her passport is in the process of being renewed. Will she be OK to cross the border into the US and back again into Canada with a government-issued license and a birth certificate?

Comment: How do you travel?

Comment: What are the nationalities of you and your daughter?

Comment: @user102008 Canadian, given the tag

Comment: @Coke Canada does not issue passport cards.

Comment: @phoog When writing that commnet, I assumed they were Americans, then I saw the tag and forgot to edit the comment

Answer (score 2):

By land Canadian citizens can use a passport, NEXUS/FAST/SENTRI card or enhanced driver's licence/provincial ID. A birth certificate alone is accepted if she's below 16 years old.

By air, only a passport or NEXUS card is accepted.

Comment: That would be "enhanced driver's license/provincial ID."  Canadian citizens who are permanent residents of the US can also use their green cards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try... but she is required to have a WHTI-compliant form of identification.  This would be a passport, an enhanced driver's license (most Canadian provinces do not have these, and those that do charge additional fees for them), or a trusted traveler card such as NEXUS (which takes special effort to get).

Does she have an expired passport?  This, combined with the ID you mentioned, and she may be admitted.  And unless there is a long drive to the border, there is little harm in trying.  But there is a decent chance that she will be denied admittance into the United States.  Ideally she should have applied for her passport some time ago, or paid for rush service.